# Why do some forms add ?action=submit to URL

Tags: php, forms

I have a bunch of php pages with forms in them.

I have some working forms that pre-existed before I started on the site - they all work as expected, so I've used those to model the new ones that I'm writing.

What I don't understand is that in the old/working ones , when the form is submitted and does not pass validation, the URL remains as is, ie, '/form-name.php'

Whereas since duplicating these, my new forms add to the URL like '/form-name.php?action=submit'

I am using the same action in my forms as the existing ones:

```
<form id="standard" action="?action=submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The top of all the php script processes the form via

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
    if($_REQUEST['action'] == "submit") {
```

What I notice is that the existing forms, as they check validation, they simply pop back to the top of the page - whereas my new forms, they actually refresh the page, as though it submits, finds errors and then reloads the page.

So i'm just trying to understand the difference, what determines how each form reacts on submit.

Edit: more info, i'll add the following js functions that are included:

```
$(window).load(function () {
if($("#standard").length != 0) {        
    $("#standard").validate();
    $.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");
}

$("#standard").submit(function() {
    var tmpError = false;

    // Disability
    if($("input[name='disability']:checked").val() =="Yes") {
        if($("#disability-text").val() == "") {
            $("#disability-text-error").slideDown('fast');
            tmpError = true;
        } else {
            $("#disability-text-error").slideUp('fast');
            tmpError = false;
        }
    }
if(tmpError) { return false; }
});
```

There is more in the above .submit function, but none of the fields that i'm looking at are included.
For eg, there is no mention of this below "file" field in the whole JS:

```
                <tr><td><div class="field"><input type="file" size="33" name="file[]" validate="required:true" value="<?=$value['file']?>"><img src="../_images/icons/asterisk.gif" alt="Mandatory" style="margin-left: 10px" /><br />
                <label class="error" for="file[]">This field is required</label></div></td></tr>
```

**EDIT** I have narrowed it down to the following:

the existing old code uses jquery scripts for validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
```

To add autocomplete functionality to some fields, I added:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_import/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_import/js/jquery-ui.css">
```

And BAM, that breaks something - when I removed those includes and my autocomplete functionality, my new forms now act the same way - ie, they dont refresh and there is no "?action=submit" added to the URL.

Has anyone experienced this conflict ?

Comment: To let the same page handle both the form, and the result, using `?action`, the php script can make a distinction between both.

Comment: For us to understand what happens when the form is processed, we would need to see examples of the PHP code for both an old and new form.

Comment: yeh i know @MichaelBerkowski but thats a lot of code to post, thats why i'm wondering how to troubleshoot; what to look for

Comment: You don't have to post all of it, just the parts that deal with the form actions and abbreviate the validation.

Comment: Do the old forms do any JavaScript validation? That would be one possible way for them to return without appearing to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a programmer doesn't want to create another file to handle the request so he just adds this GET parameter manually to the forms target and checks somewhere on the **same** page, if this parameter is set so he knows the form was run.